# Can we have a new mandatory tag on meta for proposals?

Tags: feature-request, tags, meta, required-tags

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) is for reproducible problems due to software (including styling, browser compatibility, the mobile apps, etc.).

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is for proposed new features or modifications to existing features.

[support](/questions/tagged/support) is for issues with using existing features.

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) is for things that don't have a clear-cut answer and likely have different opinions on the subject.

I propose a new tag: [proposal](/questions/tagged/proposal). This tag would be useful on Meta.SE, as well as site metas, to discuss proposed changes to things that don't fall under feature requests. I suspect this would likely be site guidelines, policies, and docs (help center).

Alternatively, perhaps [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) should be changed to [change-request](/questions/tagged/change-request) to be more general. To me, a feature request involves some kind of development. The kinds of things I think of when I think proposals likely involve no development - updating a help center page (especially ones that site mods can edit), adding or changing an off-topic close reason, changing a workflow.

Comment: Not sure it's really required. E.g. [meta-tag:feature-request] with [meta-tag:help-center] together is quite clearly a request to change something in the help center.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The difference is who can handle it. Depending on what the proposal is, site mods could implement it, if it's on an editable help center page, an off-topic reason, or just a workflow type thing. Feature request almost implies needing development (or at least staff support) to create or enable a feature.

Comment: Then it's [tag:discussion]. The tag wiki almost sounds like the posts with this tag must be endless debates with no conclusion, but in practice an outcome of discussion may well be some concrete action, e.g., implementation of the proposal made.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday Is this question a discussion, though? I'm not seeking to discuss anything. Perhaps the right answer would be to change "feature-request" to "change-request".

Comment: If you put forward a proposal, it is up to discussion. You may decide not to participate in this discussion, which is fine.

Comment: To use your example of documentation, site mods can edit *some* pages in the help center but not others, but we can't expect users to keep track of which pages mods can edit, so it doesn't seem like it would help here.  Do you have other examples where it clearly identifies the audience?  BTW, developing documentation in a new area would be a feature request, so if you're looking to sort on devs versus CMs, I'm not sure you can.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Documentation is never a feature. A feature is functionality. Even if it takes someone other than a site mod, I think it's better to categorize on functionality changes versus other changes.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I'm a technical writer and I implement new features *all the time*, along with fixing bugs and providing support.  I think some of the work our CMs do on things like help-center pages, mod-message templates, and probably bunches of things I never see, are features too.  I think Shadow Wizard has the right of it; most feature requests have, or ought to have, additional tags, and they're relevant.  I assume that if you're a developer working on, say, review queues, you *also* don't care about feature requests for chat (any more than a regular user does), right?

Answer (score 9):

Honestly, this feels like an artificial distinction that nobody would appreciate unless they were steeped in meta quite the same way you were. "proposal" is so generic that it's bound to be even harder to use appropriately than any of the other currently-required tags. The distinction between [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [proposal] is in particular hard to define for the average user.

If you want to discuss something use [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) + whatever other tags are relevant. If you're proposing a change, use [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). For documentation and whatnot... barring something being drastically wrong... [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) is probably seldom appropriate anyway. For per-site adjustments, you will typically want to discuss a proposed change first.

Beyond that... it feels like you're overthinking it. "change-proposal" vs "proposal"? That sounds like a nightmare of indecision, and I'm on the team that *would* be putting any dev effort into the changes if required. I think we're best off keeping the current, simpler system.